# Magnetic impact driver bits

Tags: powertools, bits

I am looking to buy some magnetic impact driver bits (philips head, torx head, etc), but I have not found any online. Am I searching for the wrong thing or is this not something that is made?

Not looking for any recommendations on brand just on how to find them or a better workaround so I can drive screws one handed when needed.

Comment: you can magnetize it with another magnet by rubbing them together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bits I have go into a magnetic holder which is sufficient for most screws except, of course, the stainless ones...

Comment: When I got my first set I thought it was an extender. A year later I needed an extender and found out it was magnetic... oh well+

Comment: Thank you, I thought this may be the case, but was not sure.